# SequenceEqual not calling Equals in parent type

Tags: c#, comparison

A parent type:

```
public class IdObject : IComparable<IdObject>, IEquatable<IdObject>
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(IdObject other)
    {
        if (other == null) return this == null;
        if (this == null) return false;
        var test = other.id.CompareTo(this.id);

        return other.id.CompareTo(this.id) == 0;
    }

    public int CompareTo(IdObject other)
    {
        return other.id.CompareTo(this.id);
    }
}
```

A child:

```
public class NamedObject : IdObject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Comparing lists of `IdObject`s

```
var list1 = new List<IdObject>()
{
    new IdObject() { id = 42 },
    new IdObject() { id = 43 }
};
var list2 = new List<IdObject>()
{
    new IdObject() { id = 43 },
    new IdObject() { id = 42 }
};
list1.Sort();
list2.Sort();
var test = list1.SequenceEqual(list2); // True
```

Comparing lists of `Named`s

```
var list1 = new List<NamedObject>()
{
    new NamedObject() { id = 42 },
    new NamedObject() { id = 43 }
};
var list2 = new List<NamedObject>()
{
    new NamedObject() { id = 43 },
    new NamedObject() { id = 42 }
};
list1.Sort();
list2.Sort();
var test = list1.SequenceEqual(list2); // False
```

I realized that `IdObject::Equals` is not called through a `NamedObject` context.

Am I doing something wrong ?
Isn't supposed to call the inherited `Equals` ?
How can I use the parent's `Equals` ?

Comment: Your `Equals` method has a bug: `if (other == null) return this != null;` seems wrong and should be `if (other == null) return false;` because `this` will never be `null` and doesn't equal `null`. (not the answer though)

Comment: Good catch, I'll fix that already thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, you've got a problem because your type doesn't override `object.Equals(object)` in a way consistent with your `IEquatable<T>` implementation *and* you're dealing with a collection of the subclasses.

`SequenceEqual` will be using `EqualityComparer<NamedObject>.Default`. That will check whether `NamedObject` implements `IEquatable<NamedObject>` - and will find that it doesn't, so it will fall back to calling `object.Equals(object)`. You can see this here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Base : IEquatable<Base>
{
    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Equals(object)");
        return false;
    }

    public bool Equals(Base other)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Equals(Base)");
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() => 0;
}

public class Derived : Base
{
}

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var comparer = EqualityComparer<Derived>.Default;        
        Console.WriteLine(comparer.Equals(new Derived(), new Derived()));
    }
}
```

You don't override `object.Equals(object)`, so you've effectively got reference equality.

I would recommend that you override `object.Equals(object)` and `object.GetHashCode()` in your base class.

You *could* then also implement `IEquatable<NamedObject>` in `NamedObject`, just delegating to the base implementation or (better) checking the name as well, unless you really don't want that to be taken into account.

Comment: Works fine by overriding the base `Equals`. I'll dive deeper into the docs since I don't really get the `HashCode` concept yet though